# d3 - get scale of x an y for label

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created an x and y scale like this:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 20])
    .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 20])
    .range([height, 0]);
```

I then use this to create an x and y axis as well as how to position a line with respect to these axis:

```
var line = {
    start: {x: 2, y: 3, type: 'start'},
    finish: {x: 14, y: 6, type: 'finish'} 
  };

var g = svg.append('g');

  g.append('line')
      .style('stroke', 'blue')
      .attr('class', 'line')
      .attr('x1', xScale(line.start.x))
      .attr('y1', yScale(line.start.y))
      .attr('x2', xScale(line.finish.x))
      .attr('y2', yScale(line.finish.y));
```

I also position labels that tell where the x and y axis of the line are.  The end points of the line are draggable but I can't get the scaled coordinates in the drag event:

```
var drag = d3.behavior
     .drag()
     .on("drag", function(d) {
        var circle = d3.select(this),
            line = d3.select('.line'),
            isStart = circle.classed('start'),
            textClass = isStart ? ".textstart" : ".textfinish",
            lineX = isStart ? 'x1' : 'x2',
            lineY = isStart ? 'y1' : 'y2',
            text = d3.select(textClass);

        text.text( function (d) { return "( " + d.x  + ", " + d.y +" )"; });

        line.attr(lineX, d3.event.x).attr(lineY, d3.event.y);
        text.attr('x', d3.event.x).attr('y', d3.event.y - 20);
        circle.attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
     });
```

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tasofix/1/edit?js,output) that shows the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest you change the line:

```
text.text( function (d) { return "( " + d.x  + ", " + d.y +" )"; });
```

to:

```
text.text( function (d) { return "( " + d3.format(",.2f")(xScale.invert(d.x))  + ", " + d3.format(",.2f")(yScale.invert(d.y)) +" )"; });
```

That way you will display the value you want as in the following image:

[image]

The reason this happens is because the object `d` you are passing to the function, is the d3.behaviour which has as a x, and y, the mouse locations of where you dragged to. Thus you need to use `invert` so as to convert the x,y mouse coordinates, to their corresponding x,y values of the xScale, and yScale respectively.

The unfortunate thing is that in your object `line`, you have x, and y and this must have caused the confusion.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that, could you please explain why this works?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope it is clearer now. :)